# What array type is this?

Tags: c#, arrays

```
Levels
{
    Flags
    {
        "reservation"   "a"         //Reserved slots
        "generic"       "b"         //Generic admin, required for admins
        "kick"          "c"         //Kick other players
        "ban"           "d"         //Banning other players
        "unban"         "e"         //Removing bans
        "slay"          "f"         //Slaying other players
        "changemap"     "g"         //Changing the map
        "cvars"         "h"         //Changing cvars
        "config"        "i"         //Changing configs
        "chat"          "j"         //Special chat privileges
        "vote"          "k"         //Voting
        "password"      "l"         //Password the server
        "rcon"          "m"         //Remote console
        "cheats"        "n"         //Change sv_cheats and related commands

        "custom1"       "o"
        "custom2"       "p"
        "custom3"       "q"
        "custom4"       "r"
        "custom5"       "s"
        "custom6"       "t"

        "root"          "z"
    }
}
```

This is a sourcemod configuration file, i'm curious about what array type is it, i want to start parsing it using C#.

I know that isn't JSON/PHP ARRAY or basic C# array, so what is it?

It holds a main key, a subkey and subkey variables..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stop downvoting without saying anything -.- This does not help anyone

Comment: It's a text file, which is parsed by a program. It doesn't have to correspond to any particular language's syntax (except its own).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question is lacking somewhat in clarity.

Comment: It can't be dictionary<string, string>, dictionary forces you to have just one unique KEY with a variable, this example shows one key with multiple variables..

Comment: @hatchet "Flags" it's a key, which has 21 subkeys, it may work by creating an class like.. internal class Flags { Dictionary<string,string> test = new dictionary<string,string>; } and add the predefinied keys to the 'test' dictionary, then importing to the main dictionary and forming this big array.. seems like.

Answer (score -2):

As for the comments i received, looks like it's not a array type.. just a text file which helps the program to understand it..

To create it via C# it's pretty simple.

```
Dictionary<string, Flags> test = new Dictionary<string, Flags> ();

void Populate()
{
   Flags test2 = new Flags();
   var returnx = test2.Return();
   test.Add("Levels", returnx);
}

internal class Flags
{
   Dictionary<string,string> Flags = new Dictionary<string,string>();

   public Dictionary<string, string> Return()
   {
     Flags.Add("reservation", "a");
     Flags.Add("generic", "b");
     // Etc...
     return Flags;
   }
}
```

Thanks anyway for help lads.